# Google App Script job fails(UrlFetchApp.fetch)

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

When I try to get data by below code, it will display("The value 'ASNP' does not exist for the field 'project'."):

```
var TOKEN = "key"
var options = {
  contentType: "application/json",
  headers: {"Authorization": " Basic " + TOKEN}
};
var requestUrl = "https://jiracloud.xxx.com.br/rest/api/2/search?startIndex=0&maxResults=2&jql=project=ASNP";
var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestUrl, options).getContentText();
```

But when I request by curl, it works normally:

```
curl -H " Basic key" https://jiracloud.xxx.com.br/rest/api/2/search?startIndex=0&maxResults=2&jql=project=ASNP
```

So, I think there are issue on `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` function.(If I get data form ASGS, it works normally, too.)

For `UrlFetchApp.fetch`, are there any restrictions on the use of this method? Or is this a bug? Or does my script need improvement?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add more details of the API  / service that you are calling.... P.S. Yes, UrlFetchApp has some "restrictions" i.e. it uses the a range of IP addresses, some parameters can't be set like a custom user-agent, etc.

Comment: Can I ask you about the status code from `UrlFetchApp.fetch`?